# access path of file in android as a string

Tags: java, android, file, fonts

I am looking for access the path of file in assets folder, I have tried this code but I didn't get the real path of the file

```
File file = new File("file:///android_asset/fonts/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf");
        String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

if there "android_asset" refer to assets folder?
and how can i get the file path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Font urFontName = FontFactory.getFont("assets/fonts/arial.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to access custom fonts under assets folder.

```
  TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
  Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/yourfont.ttf");
  myTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Comment: I am sorry but this code will not get the path as a string, I found this code which solve my problem

Font urFontName = FontFactory.getFont("assets/fonts/arial.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
thank you.